# react unit testing - Enzmye shallow

Tags: reactjs, jsx, enzyme

I am trying to setup unit testing in React with Enzyme. When i run the command "npm-test" the test fails. 
The console terminal indicates that it failed because of shallow(). 
I have installed enzyme using this command npm install --save enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16 react-test-renderer. Do anyone know how to solve this issue?

Below is the component

```jsx
import React from 'react';

    class Login extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div><input
          onChange={(event) => {
             this.setState({input: event.target.value})}}
          type="text" /></div>;
      }
    }

    export default Login;
```

This is the unit test i have written for the Component.

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import Login from '../../../src/components/authentication/Login';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

  it("should create an entry in component state with the event value", () => {
    // given
    const component = shallow(<Login/>);
    const form = component.find('input');
    // when
    form.props().onChange({target: {
      name: 'myName',
      value: 'myValue'
    }});
    // then
    expect(component.state('input')).toEqual('myValue');
  });
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So what is the actual error message?

Comment: There could just be some issues with enzyme-adapter-react-16. looks like they have 311 open issues : https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues?page=3&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen i ran your code with 15.4 and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi perhaps you miss the conventions:

you have to put your test files inside a `__tests__` directory and tests file should be named: `YourComponent.test.js`

Than wrap your test within a test suite:

```
describe('Your test suite', () => {
  test('it should do something', () => {
   // the content of your test
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried put the login and Login.test.jsin the same folderand now iam getting this error    
 ● Test suite failed to run
ReferenceError: Component is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/authentication/Login.js:3:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/authentication/Login.test.js:5:14)
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: Peharps you didn't define `Component` in your components: `import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Comment: i forgot to add import React, { Component } from 'react';

Comment: Ok so it's an easy fix

Comment: Thanks for the help. I spend fair too long on this ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170231/discussion-between-t3-rry-and-great-khan-2016).